# What is the method of attraction between two sheets of material with a fluid in between

Tags: classical-mechanics

If you take two sheets of finished metal for example and put oil between them they are almost impossible to separate perpendicular to the contact plane. Sheets of glass and water have the same property.

What is the reason for this attraction? Van der Waal, surface tension, suction, or some sort of adhesion of thin films? I have tried researching this based upon those topics, but can't seem to find any information that shows a definite relationship.

Thanks!

Comment: some need external pressure

Comment: Adhesion AFAIK,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adhesion  apologise if you have already read this though